# CREATE and DROP a table while another statement is in place

Tags: c, sqlite

In my previous implementation, I was streaming results from a sqlite3 table directly into my output application.  However, since I am changing the interface to a temporary data structure, I now need to get the number of rows.  The preferred way to do that seems to be with a temporary table, so my original

```
sprintf(query,"SELECT %s AS x, AVG(%s) AS y, AVG((%s)*(%s)) AS ysq FROM %s WHERE %s=%s AND %s GROUP BY x;",x,y,y,y,from,across,val,where);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &acResult,NULL);
while(sqlite3_step(acResult)==SQLITE_ROW) { ... }
sqlite3_finalize(acResult);
```

turns into

```
sprintf(query,"CREATE TEMP TABLE tt AS SELECT %s AS x, AVG(%s) AS y, AVG((%s)*(%s)) AS ysq FROM %s WHERE %s=%s AND %s GROUP BY x;",x,y,y,y,from,across,val,where);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &acResult,NULL);
sqlite3_step(acResult);
sqlite3_finalize(acResult);

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tt;", -1, &acResult, NULL);
sqlite3_step(acResult);
int length = sqlite3_column_int(acResult,0);
sqlite3_finalize(acResult);

sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT x,y, ysq FROM tt;", -1, &acResult, NULL);
while(sqlite3_step(acResult)==SQLITE_ROW) { ... }
sqlite3_finalize(acResult);
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "DROP TABLE tt;", -1, &acResult, NULL);
sqlite3_step(acResult);
sqlite3_finalize(acResult);
```

Now, this mostly works.  The problem is that I have this inside a loop across another stepping query, which seems to be responsible for the table being locked when I try to drop it.  If I finalize that query, it "works" (the drop works; everything else breaks because it's part of the logic).  There is no possible way the outer query could be referencing `tt`, because I created it within that "scope".

Is there a way of reminding sqlite that it shouldn't be locked, or am I stuck switching the outer loop away from streaming as well?

This is a read-only application (with the exception of the temp table), if that helps.

Comment: it would really help to see the outer loop to ... can you put in pastebin.com ?

Comment: There should be no table locking. Please add proper [error checking](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to all `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and `sqlite3_step` calls, otherwise it's not possible to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I actually edited that out, because it made it rather long.  The thrown error there is `6:database table is locked`, with respect to the `step` command for the `DROP TABLE` query.  The outer query is `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';`, implemented as a standard `prepare()`/`step`.